# Should I format all disks after fdisk?

Tags: partitioning, filesystems, formatting, fdisk

I created disks with fdisk:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *         xxx         xxx         xxx   83  Linux
/dev/sda2             xxx         xxx         xxx   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3             xxx         xxx         xxx   8e  Linux LVM
```

(Sytems are created using fdisk's `t` command)

Should I now format each disk using mkfs on /dev/sdaX?

Comment: Depends, what are you trying to do? What OS are you using? Are you installing a new system?

Answer (score 0):

Do a `ls /dev/sd*` and see if the device names show up.

If they don't show up, do this:

`/sbin/blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sda`

If they still don't show up,. reboot.

I know `cfdisk`, which is what I usually use, causes the partition table to update afterward.  Not sure about `fdisk`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do that if you want a particular FS on that partition.

You can achieve that by using the `mkfs` suite. (You can add more FS to the `mkfs` suite by installing `exfat-utils`, `ntfs-3g` and so on, if you're trying to set up a Windows Box for example.)